# Existentialism today

Tags: idioms

My friend asked me, "What is an existential threat? How is the word "existential" being used? Can't be the way it was used back when everybody was reading Camus and quoting Sartre. I wonder if the word could just be omitted? Isn't a threat a threat?"

I'm curious about this and the possible ways the meaning of existentialism has changed over the decades.

I am new to this group so I hope I haven't broken any rules. I looked at the "Similar Questions" and didn't see one that is similar.

Comment: I don't think that "existential threat" is any more idiomatic or philosophical than "minor threat" is—and the latter term had enough resonance in the United States in 1980 to impel Ian MacKaye to name his Washington, D.C., hardcore band [Minor Threat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_Threat), following the demise of his earlier band, the Teen Idles.  Both _existential_ in "existential threat" and _minor_ in "_minor threat" are simple modifiers of the noun _threat_. And as RaceYorAnytime notes in an answer below, _existential_ in this context means "involving [one's] fundamental existence."

Answer (score 4):

**"Existential"** means "of or relating to *existence*," so an "existential threat" is one that threatens the very *existence* of an entity. For instance, one might say:

> the proliferation of nuclear weapons poses an existential threat to the human race [because it threatens their very existence].

**"Existentialism"** is a branch of philosophy that is concerned with the "analysis of human existence," to quote from the *OED*.

> A philosophical movement or approach which focuses on the analysis of human existence and on individual human beings as agents freely determining by their choices what they will become. Also sometimes applied to other philosophies which lay particular stress on existence as distinct from essence.

So while they share the same root, the two words here might not be as related as you're assuming.

It's worth noting that the adjectival form of "existentialism" is actually **"existentialist,"** not "existential."  So the phrase,

> An existentialist threat

...would mean a threat related to the philosophy or practice of existentialism, and it would indeed be a strange turn of phrase.

---

Source: *Oxford English Dictionary*

Comment: Your first explanation is indeed very accurate @RaceYouAnytime. See https://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/704595 You can cite this as an example of current usage if you want. Simple yet perceptive answer, and I upvotes!